# How to return a remaining data from table B in sql

Tags: sql

I have a table A

Companyid ForYear , value

I have another table B

CompanyID , MarketID

Let say in table A i have 2 records

| Companyid | ForYear | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2022 | 89 |
| 5 | 2022 | 78 |
| 4 | 2021 | 89 |

and in Table B I have companies

| CompanyID | MarketID |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 3 |

Now i want to query like this ... I need to return the companies from table A and The remaining companies that are not exists in table A(Year specific) , the companies remining will have values 0

my output would be

```
3 2022 89
5 2022 78
4 2022 0
6 2022 0
4 2021 89
3 2021 0
5 2021 0
6 2021 0
```

Comment: I'd add another 2022 row to the Table A sample data, to make the problem clearer.

Comment: @jarlh I have added another record

Comment: @Filburt, those MD style tables are such a waste of screen height, and harder to read.

Comment: @jarlh I found it harder to read them without column headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with cross joining the distinct years and TableB. Then left join TableA go get the Value column (if existing).

```
select b.companyid, years.ForYear, coalesce(a.value, 0)
from (select distinct ForYear from TableA) years
cross join TableB b
left join TableA a on a.Companyid = b.Companyid
                  AND Years.ForYear = A.ForYear   -- Probably needed too, see @Saurabh Maurya's answer.
```

Note that `value` is a SQL reserved word, so you might need to *delimit* it as `"Value"`. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SQL_reserved_words)

Other than that, the question is Core ANSI/ISO SQL compliant - i.e. expected to run on *any* dbms.

Answer (score 3):

```
 SELECT 
    B.CompanyID, 
    Years.ForYear,
    COALESCE(A.value, 0) AS value
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT ForYear FROM A) Years
CROSS JOIN 
    B
LEFT JOIN 
    A ON B.CompanyID = A.CompanyID AND Years.ForYear = A.ForYear
ORDER BY 
    B.CompanyID, Years.ForYear;
```

first this query creates a list of distinct years from table A and performs a CROSS JOIN with table B to generate all combinations of companies and years. It then uses a LEFT JOIN to bring in the values from table A, and the COALESCE function is used to replace null values with 0.

Comment: `AND Years.ForYear = A.ForYear` seems to be a good idea. Upvoted!